# How to find all missing primary keys?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My database collects data from an API which comes in a paginated format. From time to time a page is not collected. I am attempting to get a list of all missing primary keys.

Following query gets the first missing id, but how to collect all the missing ids?

```
var query = "SELECT MIN(ogc_fid + 1) FIRST_GAP FROM " + 
table["name"] + " a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM " + 
table["name"] + " b WHERE b.ogc_fid = a.ogc_fid + 1) AND "+
"a.ogc_fid <> (SELECT max(c.ogc_fid) FROM " + table["name"] + " c);";
```

I would also be happy if it just showed a range like 200 - 500.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your query is correct. What if the `ogc_fid` columns start numbering from 1 but now the lowest value is 5? The first gap range should be 1 .. 4.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table table1(ogc_fid int primary key);

insert into table1 values
  (5),
  (8),
  (9),
  (17),
  (24)
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select ifnull(t2.ogc_fid, 0) + 1 as start, t1.ogc_fid - 1 as end from table1 t1
left join table1 t2 on
t2.ogc_fid = (
    select ogc_fid from table1
    where ogc_fid < t1.ogc_fid
    order by ogc_fid
    desc limit 1
)
where t1.ogc_fid <> 1 and
not exists (select ogc_fid from table1 where ogc_fid = t1.ogc_fid - 1)
order by start, end
;
```

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 10 | 16 |
| 18 | 23 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dsfTxPYs2qAck7JYZMBYqt/0)